# Powershell work in console but not in .reg file

Tags: powershell, datetime, rename

I want to have a action in the conceptual menu of windows to remplace " copy" from filename by the current date, or the date of creation.

So i have write in Powershell:

```
( Get-Item '%1' ) | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.Replace(' - Copie',' ' + $(get-date -uformat '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')) + $_.extension}
```

And it is working. (replacing `'%1'` by `*`)

But when i put it in a `.reg` textfile, and use it, like this :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\RenameWithTimestamp]
@="PostFixe avec Date"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\RenameWithTimestamp\Command]
@="PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \"( Get-Item '%1' ) | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.Replace(' - Copie',' ' + $(get-date -uformat '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M')) + $_.extension}\""
```

It does nothing.

Where is my mistake ?

Willy

Comment: I was inspired by https://superuser.com/questions/1575864/postfix-datetime-when-backup-the-files-in-same-folder

Answer (score 0):

The answer :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\RenameWithTimestamp]
@="PostFixe avec Date"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\RenameWithTimestamp\Command]
@="PowerShell -Command \"gi '%1' | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}{2}' -f $_.BaseName.Replace('- Copie', ''), ( Get-Date ), $_.Extension }\""
```